# how to use pure sql function in laravel - php

Tags: php, laravel

How can I use a pure SQL function in Laravel to delete all rows in an specific table named `logs` which `created_at` column in for more than 3 days ago.

From pure SQL i mean create whole query inside string and not using any ORM Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Raw SQL Queries**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#running-queries).

The `delete` method should be used to delete records from the database.

```php
DB::delete('delete from logs where datediff(now(), logs.created_at) > 3');
```

---

#### Running Raw SQL Queries

The `DB` facade provides methods for each type of query: `select`, `update`, `insert`, `delete`, and `statement`.

**`SELECT`**

```
DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

**`INSERT`**

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);
```

**`UPDATE`**

```
DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = ?', ['John']);
```

**`Statement`**

```
DB::statement('drop table users');
```